# Python casting error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, string, casting

This is my code:

```
def arearectangle(length, breadth):
        totalarea = length * breadth
        return totalarea


def areasqr(side):
    ''' Objective : To compute the area of circle
   Input parameters : Length and Breadth
   Return Value : area - numeric Value
    :rtype: int'''
    area = side*side
    return area


def addition(num1, num2):
    '''The objective of this proram is to find the sum of two integers
     input through keyboard'''
    total = num1 + num2
    return total


def main ():
    print ("enter the length and breadth to find the area of rectangle")
    l1 = input(int('enter the length:'))
    l2 = input(int('enter the breadth'))
    rectarea = arearectangle(l1, l2)
    print("area of the rectangle is", rectarea)
    print("enter the following values to obtain the area of square")
    s1 = int(input('first side of square : intiger value :'))
    areas = areasqr(s1)
    print("Area of Square is ", areas)
    print("enter the following value to find out the sum")
    i = int(input('enter the first intiger : '))
    j = int(input('enter the seoond intiger : '))
    newtotal = addition(i, j)
    print('the sum of the entered intger is ', newtotal)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

it throws the following error:

```
  File "", line 22, in main
    l1 = input(int('enter the length:'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'enter the length:'
```

Comment: What error....?

Comment: What error? Please describe the problem clearly. Read the [ask] page.

Comment: Have you looked at your own question? If so, do you honestly think it is acceptable?

Comment: How was it going? Did my answer work? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the casting at the wrong place.

Remove the `int()` cast, bring it outside the `input()`

```
l1 = int(input('enter the length:'))
l2 = int(input('enter the breadth'))
```

That would fix it.